# Scanning sentences from an Android Raw Resource file

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner, android-resources

I added a sample text file in Android res/raw folder and I am trying to add each line of the file into a String array list.

For e.g., say the sample text file contains the following lines

> Sample Line One
>
> Sample Line Two
>
> Sample Line Three

I would like to add these three sentences as three Strings into a String Array List. I tried the following piece of code:

```
List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();    
Scanner s = null;
s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample));
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    sampleList.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

The above code adds each word in the array list and results in an array size of 9 rather than adding each sentence with an expected array size of 3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [**Scanner#nextLine()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead of `Scanner#next()`

```
sampleList.add(s.nextLine());
```

Scanner use's white space as a default delimiter. `Scanner#next()` Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

You can also set the delimiter of the scanner to **next line**(\n) using [**Scanner#useDelimiter(delim)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29).

```
s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample)).useDelimiter("\n");
while (s.hasNextLine()){
   sampleList.add(s.next());
}
```

and now you can use `Scanner.next()` as it uses next line(\n) as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
s.next()
```

use

```
s.nextLine()
```

per [Scanner.nextLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)